# TSQL Raws into Columns Group by another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get desired table from start table and additionally group by another column (date).

May I have any suggestions here please how to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Also include the code that you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Case] INT
   ,[ErrorCode] CHAR(1)
   ,[Date] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Case], [ErrorCode], [Date])
VALUES (1, 'A', '2018-01-25')
      ,(1, 'B', '2018-01-15')
      ,(1, 'C', '2018-01-15')
      ,(1, 'A', '2018-01-15')
      ,(1, 'D', '2018-01-15')
      ,(1, 'A', '2018-01-15')
      --
      ,(2, 'D', '2018-01-26')
      ,(2, 'A', '2018-01-26')
      ,(2, 'D', '2018-01-25')
      ,(2, 'D', '2018-01-24')
      ,(2, 'C', '2018-01-24');

SELECT DISTINCT DS.[Case]
               ,DS.[Date]
               ,Errors.[ErrorCode]
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ' / ' + [ErrorCode]
            FROM @DataSource DSI
            WHERE DS.[Case] = DSI.[Case]
                AND DS.[Date] = DSI.[Date]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,3
        ,''
    )
) Errors ([ErrorCode])
ORDER BY [Case]
        ,[Date] DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `STRING_AGG`

Plese try this:

```
SELECT [Case], [Date], STRING_AGG (ErrorCode, '/') AS ErrorCode 
FROM Table1
Group by [Case], [Date];
```

Comment: STRING_AGG works great however it was only included at 2017.  For highest level of compatibility I'd use the "for xml path".

Comment: Hi Matthew, is that normal that for xml path works so slowly - please see my comments below.

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz.  Yes "for xml" is slow but has more compatibility. There are other options, like using clr, which are more efficient but then there are complications if you have to roll out to Azure/Amazon.

Comment: That being said, 19 minutes for 1000 rows, does seem a bit high.  Have you checked your execution plans to see where the highest impact is?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
SELECT distinct [Case], [Date],STUFF(
(SELECT '/' + ErrorCode
FROM Table1 as a
where a.[Case] = b.[Case] and  a.Date  = b.Date
ORDER BY ErrorCode
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ErrorCode
FROM Table1 as b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,

```
 select DISTINCT [Case],[Date],
    STUFF((Select '/'+ErrorCode
           from Table1 T1
           where T1.[Case]=T2.[Case]
           And  T1.[Date] =T2.[Date]
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As ErrorCode 
 from  Table1 T2
    ORDER BY [Case],[Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Yes, it works but is very slow - takes 19 minutes to process 1000 rows - is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Nonclusterd index was the key to success in that case. Now it takes 3 secs to process 80k raws!

Better than i expected:)